# Code after window.open doesn't get executed

Tags: javascript

I recently started learning javascript, and I'm currently trying to make a small script to automate a login procedure by filling the user name/password fields, and then clicking the 'Submit'-button.

My code is as follows:

```
window.open("");
document.getElementById('ctl00_Username').value = "XXXX";
document.getElementById('ctl00_Password').value="XXXX";
document.getElementById('ctl00_ButtonLogin').click();
```

If I run it once, the site is opened but no text fields are filled.
If I run the code *twice* (when the site is already opened) the login is successful.

I tried putting "console.log" after "window.open", but for some reason that never seems to get called.

What might I be doing wrong?

Edit: Removed unnecessary code. I am also no longer sure that the document-object actually points to the newly opened window. Calls to "console.log" and "alert" don't seem to do anything, either.

Is it possible to get the correct document-object from the window?
Is it even possible to use "window.open" and then access the new document-object?
Help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: you can't. You should put the `'filling code'` in the new file `(elogin/default.aspx)`

Comment: So the window.open-call, and the 'filling code' can't be run at the same time? 'Cause like I wrote in the question; Everything works if I run the script twice.

Comment: what is your code even supposed to do? window.open opens a new window, so `document = window.document` (which doesn't even make sense, document is already equal to window.document) will get the `document` property of the current window, not the one you just opened.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I was under the impression that I needed to "get" a new document-object from the window. 

The code is supposed to open the site, change the values of the requested text fields and then login to the site by calling the click()-function of the button. However, the script seems to come to a halt after window.open.

Edit: But then, how do I get the document-property of the window I just opened?

Comment: @Cethy as far as i know there isnt any javascript to do this, unless you do something like `window.open(url + "?feild1=" + myText)` but you have to know the way the target site works.

Answer (score 0):

A reference to the window is returned from the window.open call, you can use it to modify the window.

```
 win=window.open(...);
 win.document.doYourThing
```

You also probably need to wait until the document is ready (aka loaded).  Using jquery below

```
 $(win.document).ready(function() {
     //the document is loaded by here, this is probably where you should do your stuff.
 });
```

Comment: I tried this but the code inside the jquery-block never fires, for some reason.

Comment: This would work only with the new window on the same domain as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

1.Pass your values as query string. Example: www.test.com?username=bro&password=bro.
2.On the other page paste the below code.

```
$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var amount = $('money').val();
        var from = "INR";
        var to = "SGD";
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/CurrencyConversion",
        data: "{amount:" + amount + ",fromCurrency:'" + from + "',toCurrency:'" + to + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        var money = $(".money").val();
        $(".money").replace(money, data.d);
        }
        });
        });
        });
```

3.Now paste this code too.

```
var uname = getUrlVars()["username"];
var psw = getUrlVars()["password"];
```

4.You will be having values in the above variables.Enjoy doing whatever you want.