# Cannot assign text to div in newly created page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a problem here when trying to access the DOM in a newly created webpage.  Basically what the function should do is load the new webpage and assign the div "question_text" in the page questionpage.html to the text I want it to display.  But when I load the page there is nothing displayed.  I have attached all my javascript code.

```
    /**
 * Created by Alex on 24-Nov-15.
 */
$(function() {


    var questions = new array;
    var count = 0;
    addQuestions();

    function Question(questionText, possibleAnswers, chosenAnswer) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.possibleAnswers = possibleAnswers;
        this.chosenAnswer = chosenAnswer;
    }

    function addQuestions() {


        var question1 = new Question(
            "What is your first name",
            ['Alex','Angelo'],
            ""
        );

        var question2 = new Question(
            "What is your surname",
            ['Latham','Poupard'],
            ""
        );

        var question3 = new Question(
            "What is your date of birth",
            ['November 93','March 94'],
            ""
        );

        var question4 = new Question(
            "What is your postcode"
            ['G51 1HF', 'G84 8NW'],
            ""
        );



        questions.push(question1);
        questions.push(question2);
        questions.push(question3);
        questions.push(question4);
    }





});

function createWebpage() {

    window.open('../src/questionpage.html','_self');
    document.getElementById("question_text").innerHTML = questions[count].questionText;


}
```

It's this function at the bottom which is trying to assign the text to the div.

Comment: i is not defined, you are missing a loop

Comment: Where are you calling createWebpage from?

Comment: Calling createWebpage from a button at the starting page on my site, I want it to load the new page and assign the divs values

Comment: I think this is the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677497/code-after-window-open-doesnt-get-executed

Comment: Show the HTML also please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick you want to do. use Javascript default 
`sessionStorage` Change your code to this

```
function createWebpage() {

    sessionStorage.setItem("question", questions[count].questionText); 
    window.open('../src/questionpage.html','_self');
}
```

On questionpage.html page retrive the sessionStorage value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var received = sessionStorage.getItem("question");
    document.getElementById("question_text").innerHTML = received;
});
```

read more about `sessionStorage`

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
supports all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Code after window.open doesn't get executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677497/code-after-window-open-doesnt-get-executed)

Copying the appropriate response here:

---

A reference to the window is returned from the window.open call, you can use it to modify the window.

```
 win=window.open(...);
 win.document.doYourThing
```

You also probably need to wait until the document is ready (aka loaded). Using jquery below

```
 $(win.document).ready(function() {
     //the document is loaded by here, this is probably where you should do your stuff.
 });
```